# Symmetric algorithm effective key length

Tags: keys, symmetric, key-size

If we have a symmetric algorithm with key length $m$ bit, and we do a 5 time encryption with it.
How much will it be its effective key length.

Comment: I don't get that solution; what does it cost to brute force the key in your opinion? Besides that, I don't know how good your math is. Mine is pretty bad, but that solution, sheesh.

Comment: Yes. For example in book i read about Triple Des  There are 22k possibilities to run through all possible keys of two encryptions or
decryptions. In the case of 3DES, this forces an attacker to perform 2^112 key tests,
which is entirely infeasible with current technology. In summary, the meet-in-themiddle attack reduces the effective key length of triple encryption from 3κ to 2κ.
Because of this, it is often said that the effective key length of triple DES is 112 bits
as opposed to 3 · 56 = 168 bits which are actually used as input to the cipher.

Comment: What makes 3 key triple DES and 2 key triple DES different? What about one-key triple DES? Or, from an entirely different perspective, what if I extended the number of rounds of a cipher by a factor 3?

Comment: Final hint, using my mod powers :) How many keys are you using in your question? How is brute force, i.e. trying all the keys affected in that case?

Comment: Hmm, in hindsight that question doesn't specify if 5 different keys are used or not.

Comment: if we do a 5 time encryption with 5 different keys then the effective key length is 2^(5m)

Comment: Alright. In that case a meet in the middle is possible, and you have to perform ceil(encryptions / 2) calls of the cipher with different keys. The effective key length is then that number times the key size (+ a similar or much smaller number). If there is just one key then of course the brute force doesn't take any time, and the key strength remains the same.

Comment: So that means for different keys is ceil(5/2) = ceil(2.5) = 3 so its this number times the key size : so 3 * 2^m. (What is that + a similiar or smaller number ?).  When the keys are the same then 2^m.

Comment: Well, yes, now you are getting there. However, you ask for effective key length. That's then just $3 \cdot m$ of course, as the key length is already in bits. $2^{3 \cdot m}$ would then be the effort required. Of course there is also a non-negligible amount of memory required, and a rather large but negligible amount of effort for performing the $2^{2 \cdot m}$ calculations for the meet in the middle.